# Proper Burpee Form

Tags: form, crossfit

When doing burpees (or actually watching others more seasoned than I) I notice that "on the way up" their feet are both pointing forward, however, mine always come back "pigeon toed".

I assume this is because my hips are VERY TIGHT; is there some sort of stretching, etc I can do to help me with proper burpee form?

Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong on this; I don't think it is wrong if your feet point outward to a certain extent.

Comment: For toe positioning, I'm guessing a lot of the discussions on this with regards to squats would help understand advantages/disadvantages to each position (i.e. what muscles are being worked; what are the effects on joints; which are easier/harder, etc.). For tight hips, consider a daily regiment of working with hurdles (go under back and forth, lift legs over a bunch, etc.). Also static glute stretches should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For burpees I believe they are supposed to be forward our slightly toed out as you should be in a squat stance. See Crossfit - How Do I Burpee (http://www.crossfit.com/cf-info/faq.html#Exercises8) for explanation of their standard.

For tight hips I think this article does a good job of covering some ways to work on this. (http://www.marksdailyapple.com/how-to-regain-and-maintain-hip-mobility/)
Personally I find foam rolling my IT band (runs down outside of thighs) as well as leg swings(hold onto something and swing one leg at a time front to back, then side to side) and hip thrusts(hold hands on hips and push out) are fairly easy and do a good job. Also note that a lot of time spent sitting will negatively impact your hip mobility, so less time in a chair should help.

If the hip mobility doesn't fix your form have a trainer watch you to see if there is anything you aren't noticing or other possible corrections.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynammic Stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_stretching)

[Tom Kurz](http://tomkurz.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/benefits-of-stretching-not-and-more/)

I used this when training in martial arts many years ago. To this day, if asked, I can still kick above my head from cold.

Comment: Please elaborate the contents of the link here.